# Angular2+ whole DOM flicker on component load ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When a user clicks an item it adds it to a list. To render the list i'm using an ngFor. After the user adds the first item to the selected list the whole screen/DOM flickers (everything disappears and reappears). This does not happen when the user then adds a second element to the selected array

Here is my ngFor loop:

```
<div
  *ngFor="let sel of selected"
    class="cw-selected-list-item"
 >
 <div class="cw-selected-name t4">{{ sel.id }}</div>
   <app-checkbox class="cw-selected-r-tick"></app-checkbox>
   <app-checkbox class="cw-selected-rw-tick"></app-checkbox>
 </div>
```

When I comment out my app-checkbox components the flicker does not appear. Below is my app-checkbox component

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
 selector: "app-checkbox",
 templateUrl: "./checkbox.component.html",
 styleUrls: ["./checkbox.component.scss"],
})
export class CheckboxComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() checked = false;
 @Output() checkChanged = new EventEmitter();

constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {}

toggleChecked() {
  this.checked = !this.checked;
  this.checkChanged.emit(this.checked);
 }
}
```

HTML

```
<div
 class="checkbox clickable"
 [ngClass]="{ 'checkbox-active': this.checked }"
 (click)="toggleChecked()"
>
<img
 class="checkbox-image"
 [ngStyle]="{ opacity: !this.checked ? 0 : 1 }"
 src="assets/buttons/tick.png"
/>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT

When the user clicks it simply call this function

```
  selected = [];

  public addToSelected(item: Document) {
   this.selected.push(item);
  }
```

HTML

```
    <div
      *ngFor="let hit of hits"
       class="aisd-hit t4"
       [ngClass]="{ 'hit-disabled': this.isAlreadySelected(hit) }"
       (click)="
          this.isAlreadySelected(hit) ? undefined : this.addToSelected(hit)
        "
     >
```

isAlreadySelected function

```
  isAlreadySelected(doc: Document) {
   return this.selected.includes(doc);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide all code that makes changes to the `selected` array (or a reproducer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

It was importing my fonts locally through .woff2 files which was creating a full DOM refresh when a new component was created after view init.

Hope this helps someone

Example import:

```
  url(/assets/fonts/opensans/mem8YaGs126MiZpBA-UFUZ0bbck.woff2)
  format("woff2");
```

Comment: I don't understand what you changed to fix the problem?

Comment: I was loading my fonts through local files in my assets folder (for offline Electron use) changing to load fonts from Google remotely fixed the issue. Not sure why but loading from local caused the DOM to flicker/refresh @igg